# inserting data into related tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert all the data for one object (which spans one main table and two related tables) in one statement if possible. If I were to only have one related table, I assume I could do something like this using Common Table Expressions:

```
WITH foo AS (INSERT INTO foos VALUES (....) RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (foo.id....)
```

Am I able to do something like this but for more than one related table?

Comment: You can do this using  trigger

Comment: a trigger isn't a single statement though!

Comment: You can use multiple CTEs for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your format to as many tables as needed. Here is an example with one main table and two related tables, and several ways of getting back the end results:

These are the tables used:

```
 CREATE TABLE main
 (
     main_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
     main_text text
 ) ;
 CREATE TABLE age
 (
     main_id integer REFERENCES main(main_id) PRIMARY KEY,
     birthdate date NOT NULL,
     CHECK(birthdate <= now())
 ) ;
 CREATE TABLE preferred_colours
 (
     main_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES main(main_id),
     colour text NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(main_id, colour)
 ) ;
```

This is one CTE where you insert in three tables, and get out some results:

```
 WITH insert_main AS
 (
     INSERT INTO main (main_text)
     VALUES ('Main text')
     RETURNING main_text, main_id
 )
 , insert_age AS
 (
     INSERT INTO age (main_id, birthdate)
     VALUES ( (SELECT main_id FROM insert_main), '2017-01-01')
     RETURNING main_id, birthdate
 )
 , insert_colours AS
 (
     INSERT INTO preferred_colours (main_id, colour)
     SELECT
         main_id, colour
     FROM
         insert_main
         CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT 'blue' AS colour
          UNION 
          SELECT 'red'
          UNION
          SELECT 'green'
         ) AS colours
     RETURNING
         *
 )
 SELECT
      insert_main.main_id
     ,insert_main.main_text
     ,insert_age.birthdate
     ,(SELECT string_agg(colour, ', ' ORDER BY colour) 
       FROM insert_colours
      ) AS preferred_colours_list
 FROM
     insert_main 
     CROSS JOIN insert_age
```

```
 main_id | main_text | birthdate  | preferred_colours_list
 ------: | :-------- | :--------- | :---------------------
       1 | Main text | 2017-01-01 | blue, green, red
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=27e3d905fbec44f0af74ff7a3946cf23)*